# Problems with one-to-one, one-to-many and multithreading in Android (GreenDAO)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service, greendao

Good day. I'm new in using greendao, so my problems may seem silly to you.

I'm working on some project which contact to server and save the responses from it to database through greendao. Requests to the server are made through a service that runs in a separate thread. So, my problem is that when I put the data in the database in the service all is well. But, when I try to get them out of the database through the presenter of activity, then the fields with annotation @ToOne or @ToMany in ResponseNetermin = null. I put logs in the end of post, which can helps to understand my problem Here is some of my entities:

```
@Entity(active = true)

public class ResponseEthermine implements IResponse, Serializable {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;

    private Long workersId;
    @SerializedName("workers")
    @Expose
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "workersId")
    private WorkersEthermine workers;
    @SerializedName("unpaid")
    @Expose
    private Long unpaid;

    @SerializedName("rounds")
    @Expose
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "responseId")
    private List<RoundEthermine> rounds;

    private Long settingsId;
    @SerializedName("settings")
    @Expose
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "settingsId")
    private SettingsEthermine settings;
    @SerializedName("hashRate")
    @Expose
    private String hashRate;
    @SerializedName("avgHashrate")
    @Expose
    private Double avgHashrate;
    @SerializedName("reportedHashRate")
    @Expose
    private String reportedHashRate;

    private Long minerStatsId;
    @SerializedName("minerStats")
    @Expose
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "minerStatsId")
    private MinerStatsEthermine minerStats;
    @SerializedName("ethPerMin")
    @Expose
    private Double ethPerMin;
    @SerializedName("usdPerMin")
    @Expose
    private Double usdPerMin;
    @SerializedName("btcPerMin")
    @Expose
    private Double btcPerMin;
}

@Entity(active = true)

public class SettingsEthermine implements Serializable{

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("miner")
    @Expose
    private String miner;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("monitor")
    @Expose
    private Long monitor;
    @SerializedName("minPayout")
    @Expose
    private Long minPayout;

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1164269290012137915L;
}

@Entity(active = true)

public class WorkersEthermine implements Serializable{

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @Expose
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "workersId")
    private List<WorkerEthermine> workersEthermine;

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 2224269290012137915L;
}

@Entity(active = true)

public class WorkerEthermine implements ItemsRecyclerView, Serializable {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("worker")
    @Expose
    private String worker;
    @SerializedName("hashrate")
    @Expose
    private String hashrate;
    @SerializedName("reportedHashRate")
    @Expose
    private String reportedHashRate;
    @SerializedName("validShares")
    @Expose
    private Long validShares;
    @SerializedName("invalidShares")
    @Expose
    private Long invalidShares;
    @SerializedName("staleShares")
    @Expose
    private Long staleShares;
    @SerializedName("workerLastSubmitTime")
    @Expose
    private Long workerLastSubmitTime;
    @SerializedName("invalidShareRatio")
    @Expose
    private Long invalidShareRatio;

    private Long workersId;

    private final static long serialVersionUID = -5303263359818635190L;
}
```

The service stores the data in the database like this:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
for(ResponseEthermine response : lastResponsesEthermine) {
            databaseHelper.putResponseEthermineToDatabase(response);
        }
```

And check the result of this:

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Test. After adding to database. List of the responses from database: ");
ResponseEthermine> list = databaseHelper.getLastResponsesEthermine();
for(ResponseEthermine response : list)
            response.checkResponse();
```

As you can see it's just checking of data of object.

```
public void checkResponse(){
        String LOG_TAG = "MY_LOG " + ResponseEthermine.class.getSimpleName();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id = " + id + ",\n"
                + "address = " + address + ",\n"
                + "unpaid = " + unpaid + ",\n"
                + "settings = " + settings + ",\n"
                + "hashRate = " + hashRate + ",\n"
                + "avgHashrate = " + avgHashrate + ",\n"
                + "workers = " + workers + ",\n"
                + "rounds = " + rounds + ",\n"
                + "minerStats = " + minerStats);
    }
```

Here is my logs which can helps to understand my problems.

```
MyService: Test. Before adding to database responses looks like: 
service D/MY_LOG ResponseEthermine: id = null,
                    address = 8f7ae5c3883f1079a8c3280ef97aabdd5e9a7960,
                                        unpaid = 49120026614693020,
                    settings = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.SettingsEthermine@52e3650,
                    hashRate = 31.9 GH/s,
                    avgHashrate = 3.1756177469135803E10,
                    workers = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.WorkersEthermine@b19b049,
                    rounds = [com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.RoundEthermine@f1c7d4e, ...

service D/MY_LOG ResponseEthermine: id = null,
                    address = de088812a9c5005b0dc8447b37193c9e8b67a1ff,
                    unpaid = 0,
                                        settings = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.SettingsEthermine@2fd922b,
                    hashRate = 25.6 GH/s,
                    avgHashrate = 2.5205229938271606E10,
                    workers = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.WorkersEthermine@c28688,
                    rounds = [com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.RoundEthermine@d00e821, ...
```

Then I put responses to database. Get it and print in the logs:

```
List<ResponseEthermine> list = databaseHelper.getLastResponsesEthermine();
        for(ResponseEthermine response : list)
            response.checkResponse();
```

And logs:

```
service D/MY_LOG: MyService: Test. After adding to database. List of the responses from database:
service D/MY_LOG ResponseEthermine: id = 12,
                    address = 8f7ae5c3883f1079a8c3280ef97aabdd5e9a7960,
                    unpaid = 49120026614693020,
                                        settings = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.SettingsEthermine@52e3650,
                                        hashRate = 31.9 GH/s,
                    avgHashrate = 3.1756177469135803E10,
                    workers = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.WorkersEthermine@b19b049,
                    rounds = [com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.RoundEthermine@f1c7d4e,...
service D/MY_LOG ResponseEthermine: id = 13,
                    address = de088812a9c5005b0dc8447b37193c9e8b67a1ff,
                    unpaid = 0,
                    settings = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.SettingsEthermine@2fd922b,
                    hashRate = 25.6 GH/s,
                    avgHashrate = 2.5205229938271606E10,
                    workers = com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.WorkersEthermine@c28688,
                    rounds = [com.example.denis.miningproject20.models.ethermine.RoundEthermine@d00e821,...
```

At the current stage, I checked the tables Settings table, Runs, Workers and their size is 0.

Logs:

```
service D/MY_LOG: MyService: Test, number of items in SettingsEthermine: 0
service D/MY_LOG: MyService: Test, number of items in RoundsEthermine: 0
service D/MY_LOG: MyService: Test, number of items in WorkersEthermine: 0
```

After that I send message to the presenter of activity. In presenter I use code like this:

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This message is lastResponsesEthermine. Number of last responses from ethermine: "
    + DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getLastResponsesEthermine().size());
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Number of items in the table Rounds from ethermine: "
    + DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getListOfRoundsEthermine().size());
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Rounds from ethermine: "
    + DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getLastResponsesEthermine().get(0).getRounds());

DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getLastResponsesEthermine().get(0).checkResponse();
```

And logs:

```
D/MY_LOG: MainPresenter: This message is lastResponsesEthermine. Number of last responses from ethermine: 2
D/MY_LOG: MainPresenter: Number of items in the table Rounds from ethermine: 0
D/MY_LOG: DatabaseHelper: Get last responses from Ethermine.
D/MY_LOG ResponseEthermine: id = 12,
                address = 8f7ae5c3883f1079a8c3280ef97aabdd5e9a7960,
                                unpaid = 49120026614693020,
                                settings = null,
                                hashRate = 31.9 GH/s,
                                avgHashrate = 3.1756177469135803E10,
                                workers = null,
                                rounds = [],
                                minerStats = null
D/MY_LOG ResponseEthermine: id = 13,
                address = de088812a9c5005b0dc8447b37193c9e8b67a1ff,
                unpaid = 0,
                                settings = null,
                                hashRate = 25.6 GH/s,
                                avgHashrate = 2.5205229938271606E10,
                                workers = null,
                                rounds = [],
                                minerStats = null
D/MY_LOG: MainPresenter: Rounds from ethermine: []
```

As you can see fields with annotation @ToMany and @ToOne is empty. Please help me with advice or an example. Thank you for attention.